# SVN merge problem with "svn:mergeinfo" property

Tags: svn, merge

I have one big problem with merging - it falls on start with strange message: "Server sent unexpected return value (401 Authorization Required) in responce to PROPFIND request for '/svn/autogroup_projects/.../Data.sln'".

Really that folder is not exists in the branch, but we had it in trunc (it modificated separately). And that file is only one with property "svn:mergeinfo" and value is blank. 
And of course I have access to the SVN - 401 error code is very strange for me.

Answer (score 1):

Has the server been upgraded to SVN version 1.5.x? And more importantly, has the [repository format been upgraded to match](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.upgrade.html)?

Comment: svn - 1.5.4
And repository, i guess, has been upgraded to match (but really I don't know - admin are unavailable now)